# Blender only renders 1 file

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

when i try to render my project in EEVEE it only renders 1 frame. i have an animation of 60 frames and it only renders the first one.

Disk file:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BOkfpm8mYKwkz1WiC8LzlzQ8nlSK3JzO/view

Anybody got a solutiuon for this?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I found a fix. So in the Frame Range tab under output, you have to set the step to 1, or else it wont work